# Find Top level Parent and With Recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got two tables as following

```
 Table Person

  Id   Name
  1    A
  2    B
  3    C
  4    D
  5    E

Table RelationHierarchy

ParentId   CHildId
    2         1
    3         2
    4         3
```

This will form a tree like structure

```
      D
      |
      C
      |
      B
      |
      A
```

I am using following CTE to find top level parent

```
  DECLARE @childID INT 
  SET @childID  = 1 --chield to search

  ;WITH RCTE AS
  (
    SELECT *, 1 AS Lvl FROM RelationHierarchy 
    WHERE ChildID = @childID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT rh.*, Lvl+1 AS Lvl FROM dbo.RelationHierarchy rh
    INNER JOIN RCTE rc ON rh.CHildId = rc.ParentId
    )
   SELECT TOP 1 id, Name
   FROM RCTE r
   inner JOIN dbo.Person p ON p.id = r.ParentId
   ORDER BY lvl DESC
```

Now the problem is , incase the Person is himself a toplevel then his Id should be returned instead of no records. Do i need a temp table or table variable to check count of CTE and then return the 
@childID if Count is Zero?

Comment: I added the sql-server tag because the code looks like SQL Server code.

Comment: It seems that you need to add the top levels to your relationhierarchy table (i.e. parentID=childID)

Comment: As @Jayvee mentioned, I believe you're missing the record with `ParentId NULL and ChildId 4`. That should be your anchor in the RCTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solves your problem.  The idea is to force the start on the child rather than doing a lookup initially:

```
WITH RCTE AS
  (
    SELECT @childID as parentId, NULL as childid, 1 AS Lvl

    UNION ALL

    SELECT rh.*, Lvl+1 AS Lvl FROM dbo.RelationHierarchy rh
    INNER JOIN RCTE rc ON rh.CHildId = rc.ParentId
    )
   SELECT TOP 1 id, Name
   FROM RCTE r
   inner JOIN dbo.Person p ON p.id = r.ParentId
   ORDER BY lvl DESC;
```