# How to find Multiple Root Ids of a Node in SQL (CTE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have got two tables as following

```
 Table Person

 Id   Name
 1    A
 2    B
 3    C
 4    D
 5    E

Table RelationHierarchy

 ParentId   CHildId
    2         1
    3         2
    4         3
  This will form a tree like structure

  D
  |
  C
  |
  B
  |
  A

I am using following CTE to find top level parent

DECLARE @childID INT 
SET @childID  = 1 --chield to search

;WITH RCTE AS
 (
  SELECT *, 1 AS Lvl FROM RelationHierarchy 
  WHERE ChildID = @childID

UNION ALL

SELECT rh.*, Lvl+1 AS Lvl FROM dbo.RelationHierarchy rh
INNER JOIN RCTE rc ON rh.CHildId = rc.ParentId
  )
   SELECT TOP 1 id, Name
   FROM RCTE r
  inner JOIN dbo.Person p ON p.id = r.ParentId
  ORDER BY lvl DESC
```

Now the problem is, In Case a person is part of more than one Hierarchies i-e There are more than one Root Id's how can i find that. Can anyone should a change in above mentioned code?

Comment: Why did you not adjust your `anchor` part after asking your question yesterday here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068163/find-top-level-parent-and-with-recursive-cte It is still the same as before your original question..

Comment: I have adjusted that, actually i have copied it from my previous question